# Button click creates new JTable everytime instead of refreshing with new value

Tags: java, swing, button, onclick, jtable

I'd like to create a JTable that displays the values from a created object by clicking a button.

The object is created here:

```
    public class Getraenkeverwaltung extends Firma {
    
    public static Getraenk getraenk1 = new Getraenk(1, "Pepsi Maxx Original", 0.99, 500);
    ...
    }
```

Now with the following code I'm creating the window with all the panels.

```
        public void buildUi() {
        // Create the main window
        Frame fr = new Frame();
        fr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Define colors
        Color headerColor = new Color(38, 70, 83);
        Color contentColor = new Color(42, 157, 143);
       
        // create navigation pane at the top
        JPanel navigation = new JPanel();
        navigation.setBackground(headerColor);
        navigation.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
        navigation.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,50));

        // create content pane in the middle
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setBackground(contentColor);
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        // create footer pane at the bottom
        JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        footer.setBackground(headerColor);
        footer.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        footer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
        footer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // show impressum in the footer pane
        JLabel impressum = new JLabel(Firma.impressum());
        impressum.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); // Platziert den Text mittig
        impressum.setForeground(Color.white);
        
        // create the buttons
        Button btnBestand = new Button("Bestand anzeigen");
        Button btnVerkauf = new Button("Verkaufen");
        Button btnErhoehen = new Button("Bestand erhoehen");
        Button btnExit = new Button("Exit");

        // display beverages on button click
        btnBestand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String column [] = {"Artikelnummer", "Artikel", "Bestand"};
                Object data [][] = {
                    {getraenk1.getId(), getraenk1.getName(), getraenk1.getBestand()},
                    {getraenk2.getId(), getraenk2.getName(), getraenk2.getBestand()},
                    {getraenk3.getId(), getraenk3.getName(), getraenk3.getBestand()}
                };
                JTable table = new JTable(data, column);
                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
                content.remove(sp);
                content.revalidate();
                content.repaint();
                content.add(sp);    
            }
        });

        // open new sale window
        btnVerkauf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Verkaufen();
            }
        });

        // close the program
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // add the buttons to the navigation pane
        navigation.add(btnBestand);
        navigation.add(btnVerkauf);
        navigation.add(btnErhoehen);
        navigation.add(btnExit);

        // add the impressum to the footer pane
        footer.add(impressum, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // add the three main panels to the window
        fr.add(navigation, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        fr.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        fr.add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        fr.pack();
    }
```

One of the problems is the button functionality of **btnBestand**. Whenever I'm changing the value of some of my products, it should refresh the JTable.
Unfortunately, there's a new JTable displayed everytime I click on the button,
[so it looks like this after hitting the button four times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPVfY.png).

I'd like to just display the table with the new value after clicking on the button again.

Thanks in advance.

// edit:
Removed the `content.remove(sp);` pointed out by Gjermund Dahl, as it is unnecessary in this context. Thank you.
Problem still persists

Comment: ‘content.remove(sp)’ doesn’t remove the existing table because ‘sp’ was declared the line before.

Comment: *Button click creates new JTable* - well, why do you have a `new JTable(...)` statement in your ActionListener? If you don't want a new table then don't create a new table. Instead create a new `DefaultTableModel` and use the `setModel(...)` method of the JTable. The is no need to create the scroll pane either. Also, don't use a Button. For Swing you use a JButton.